# Vary color with height (z) for an rgl surface plot

Tags: r, rgl

I have a matrix of x,y, and z values (19,268 values) that are arranged as a surface. I plotted the surface using:

`rgl::surface3d(mat$x, mat$y, mat$z, color="grey")`

But, I want the color to vary with height (my Z values). The z-values range from `-1.377385 to 29.93678`.

How can I make my plot color vary with height?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given a reproducible example, so I don't know if these results will be satisfactory, but the general idea is that the `color` argument can be an array of the same shape as `z`, and those colours will be used at corresponding locations.

For example,

```
library(rgl)
x <- y <- seq(-1, 1, len=20)
x <- x + 0.5 # to distinguish it from y
z <- outer(x, y, function(x,y) x^2 + y^2)
col <- rainbow(10)[cut(z, breaks = 10)]
surface3d(x, y, z, color = col)
```

[image]

This gives fairly rough edges to each colour change; you could improve it by using a finer grid, or more colours.